# Onedrive Universal App Example Fail

Tags: onedrive

The OneDrive Photo Browser Universal App at https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sample-photobrowser-uwp

breaks when using the latest v2 version of the OneDrive SDK.

Specifically at Client.SignOutAsync, Client.AuthenticateAsyn and OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient.

Does anyone have a fix ?

Answer (score 2):

The Photo Browser example has been updated to reflect the v2 changes in the SDK (see [this commit](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sample-photobrowser-uwp/commit/353ca378de7faffb04baec04bf65e0a615743b86)). Are you updated to that version of the sample?

Some of the methods you referenced are not included in the SDK anymore. For example, `OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient()` has been removed. You can see in the [sample app](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sample-photobrowser-uwp/blob/master/OneDrivePhotoBrowser/AccountSelection.xaml.cs) how to get a client without using that method.